# How to import existing azure repo (as a template) into newly created azure repo

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core

I am trying to make a bot that will allow programmers in my company to quickly create a new repo that will use the same files from a template repo via import. I am currently trying to use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi with no success so far. I keep getting a Bad Request message (nothing else that would clarify what needs to be changed).
My code currently looks like this.

```
//Creates the new repository
var gitRepoOptions = new GitRepositoryCreateOptions
                {
                    Name = repoName,
                    ProjectReference = teamProjectReference
                };
//Creates VSS connection and GitHttpClient to create repository
var targetRepository = await this._azureConnection.CreateRepositoryAsync(gitRepoOptions);

//Import template Azure git repo   
var gitRepository = new GitRepository
{
    Id = targetRepository.Id
};
var gitImportGitSource = new GitImportGitSource
{
     Url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{team project}/_git/{repository}" 
     //Or this
     //Url = "https://{organization}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{team project}/_git/{repository}"
};
var gitImportRequestParameters = new GitImportRequestParameters
{
      GitSource = gitImportGitSource,
      TfvcSource = null
};
var gitImportRequest = new GitImportRequest
{
       Repository = gitRepository,
       Parameters = gitImportRequestParameters
};

//Imports azure git repo (or rather should)
await this._azureConnection.CreateImportRequestAsync(gitImportRequest, teamProjectReference.Id, targetRepository.Id);
```

Comment: at which step do you get the Bad Request error?

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have provided seems to be correct. The procedure you are following is also correct. I would suggest to use the following references -

1. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
2. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
3. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
4. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

And create the new repository in target Project as shown below.

```cs
var targetRepository = await this._azureConnection.CreateRepositoryAsync(gitRepositoryCreateOptions).Result;
```

If you are getting the bad request error in the url, which is the path of the source repository then you will need to check the path using the web debugging proxy tools like fiddler.

Also check this **[TFVC Repository Migration To GIT Repository](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/tfvc-repository-migration-to-git-repository)** example and [Import repositories from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops) document for more information.